# Order of an element of a group whose representation fulfills stability constraint

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $((\rho_{n},V_{n}))_{n>0}$ a sequence of  faithful representations of $G$ with $V_{n}$ a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dimension $n$.

Suppose that for all $g\in G$ and all positive integers $n$ and $m$, $(\rho_{mn},V_{nm})$ is the tensor product of $(\rho_{n},V_{n})$ and $(\rho_{m},V_{m})$.

Is every non trivial element of $G$ of order $2$? Are all elements of $\rho_{k}(g)$ complex numbers of modulus $1$ whatever the value of $k$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The "suppose" seems to be a definition, not an assumption.

Comment: Do you mean it's always true?

Comment: I mean that $(\rho, V_{nm})$ has no meaning in itself, except that you seem to define it as the tensor product (which has the issue that so far only the factor of degree $n$ seems to have been defined)

Comment: For $m$ greater that $n$, $(\rho,V_{m})$ is the induced representation of degree $m$ of the representation of degree $n$ $(\rho,V_{n})$.

Comment: That does not make sense. You induce from a subgroup.

Comment: Well, for $n$ less than $m$, I want the matrix of size $n$ $\rho_{n}(g)$ to be a submatrix of the matrix of size $m$ $\rho_{m}(g)$. Is it clearer that way?

Comment: And I require the equality $\rho_{mn}(g)=(\rho_{m}\otimes\rho_{n})(g)$, for all $m, n, g$.

Comment: But now you are forcing $V_1$ to be $1$ on any element for which any other representation in the sequence has non-zero character. Also, you are forcing the group be be cyclic since you require a $1$-dimensional faithful representation.

Comment: Actually my goal is to prove that if $G$ is not trivial, it is necessarily the cyclic group of order $2$. Do you think such a conclusion can be reached?

Comment: Actually, with the condition that the matrices for $n$ must be submatrices for all larger $m$, I think this is only possible for the trivial group unless I am missing something.

Comment: By submatrix of size $n$, I mean a block of size $n$, so that the matrix $a_{ij}=1_{i+j=n+1}$ is a non-trivial example. Is it the only one?